# Convert String to DateTime in C# UK and US format

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert a string to a datetime

I have been using

```
DateTime convertedDate = DateTime.Parse(lastModificationDate);
```

to convert the date

my problem is, sometimes the date will be in UK format and sometimes in US format

ie UK `11/09/2011 10:34`
US `2/28/2010 13:56`

How can I handle both formats when I am not sure which format the string will be in, ie us or uk?

Comment: That is impossible without some indication of whether it is US or UK, as you could have 2 identical strings with different meanings.  Is there no UTC version of your date available?

Comment: @JustinHarvey: What do you mean by "UTC version"? UTC isn't a format. Both of those values can be in UTC, in different formats.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You fundamentally can't. You don't have enough data. As a *human*, which date is involved here?

```
11/09/2011 10:34
```

Is that 11th of September or 9th of November?

If you can't tell the difference as a *human*, there's no chance of a computer doing so.

Now if you can get a signal from elsewhere in the same data source, then that's a start - for example, you could heuristically try to parse all the dates as US format, and all the dates as UK format, and if 100% pass as UK format but 60% fail in the US format (due to trying to days being parsed as invalid months) then you could reasonably assume they're UK dates.

That's never going to be a complete solution though - because you could have one data source with a bunch of dates which are *all* valid (but with different meanings) in both formats.

Answer (score 1):

You should be storing your date times in the database in a standardised format, usually UTC, for this very reason.

Then you can parse to the users local date time from UTC using javascript etc.

Comment: UTC isn't a format, it's a time zone (effectively). Also, there's no indication that there's a database installed here at all. If the value *is* being stored in a database, it shouldn't be stored in a string format at all.