# Get DateTime server format over FTP

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-4.5

I'm not sure if this is possible so I thought I would throw it out there.

I'm getting a load of file details over FTP using the WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails method. This is great for file names and bits like that. However when I try to parse the CreatedDate, i'm running into problems, as the date time can either be in UK format or US format, depending on which server I connect to. As discussed in this post ([Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13255484/convert-string-to-datetime-in-c-sharp-uk-and-us-format)), it is not possible to determine the format from just the date. So is it possible to get the DateTime format for the server over FTP? Get the System.Globalization.CultureInfo for the server?

Comment: Can you post examples of the different formats you are getting?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13628169/issue-with-ftpwebrequest-getdatetimestamp-and-datetime

Comment: Well it is in either UK or US format, so 21/10/2013 (UK) or 10/21/2013 (US)